# Pandas rolling by date interval returning wrong result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this data:

```py
data = {
  'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  'number': [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  'date': ['2010-01-01', '2010-01-01', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to get the mean of col number in the last 1 day.

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['mean_number'] = df['number'].rolling('1D').mean().shift()
```

Ps: I use .shift() for the mean not to include the current line

Result in this:

```py
            id  number        date  mean_number
date
2010-01-01   1       2  2010-01-01          NaN
2010-01-01   2       3  2010-01-01          2.0
2020-01-04   3       5  2020-01-04          2.5
2020-01-04   4       6  2020-01-04          5.0
2020-01-04   5       7  2020-01-04          5.5
2020-01-05   6       8  2020-01-05          6.0
```

Id 1 is right, because there is no data before.

Id 2 is right, because is doing the mean only of the id 1.

Id 3 is wrong, because I only set 1D in the rolling window, so it was only supposed to be included 2020-01-03 and 2020-01-04.

Id 4 is right, because is doing the mean only of the id 3.

Id 5 is right, because is doing the mean only of the id 3 and id 4 (the 2 are in the range of 1D).

Id 6 is right, because is doing the mean only of the id 3, id 4 and id 5 (the 3 are in the range of 1D).

What am i doing wrong and can i fix it?

Comment: What would be the explicit expected output?

Comment: Id 3 should be None, as there are no rows  before it in the 1D range.

Comment: The exact logic is still unclear to me but the culprit is the `shift`, you probably shouldn't `shift` **after** the calculation, it sets the reference to the wrong date.

Comment: The logic is that I need the rolling mean, excluding the current row. 
You already answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74069003/how-to-create-column-with-mean-of-rows-before-the-date-of-current-row 
But now I need the mean by date range.

Comment: Try to run `df['number'].rolling('1D').apply(lambda x: print(x) or 1)` to see the slice that is used at each step and see if this makes sense. A shift would mean that you just use the previous slice. In the other question this was an expanding mean, so the shift is regular, unlike here.

Comment: (disclaimer, I'm lacking some sleep, my brain might not be in the clearer state right now :p)

Comment: Yeah, it really doesn't make sense. I got it with 
`df['mean_number'] = (df['number'].rolling('1D').sum() - df['number']) / (df['number'].rolling('1D').count() - 1)`. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can reuse the rolling (`r = df['number'].rolling('1D') ; r.sum() ; r.count()`), other than that, looks quite good

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['mean_number'] = df['number'].rolling('1D', closed='left').mean()
```

Result:

```
            id  number        date  mean_number
date                                           
2010-01-01   1       2  2010-01-01          NaN
2010-01-01   2       3  2010-01-01          2.0
2020-01-04   3       5  2020-01-04          NaN
2020-01-04   4       6  2020-01-04          5.0
2020-01-04   5       7  2020-01-04          5.5
2020-01-05   6       8  2020-01-05          6.0
```

humm~ not 100% sure what u are trying to do. But u can try to set the 'closed' parameter instead of using .shift()

For more detail, u can check this out: [Windowing operation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html#window-generic)